# (MATLAB) Temporarily storing data in a GUI for plot Arithmetic

Tags: matlab, user-interface, math, plot, calculator

Hello I'm having a problem in how to go about making a GUI (using GUIDE) to do some arithmetic on some spectra files (from text files containing x data and y data). I'm trying to make something like a spectrum calculator.

So far I have two import file buttons called 'Import file 1' and 'Import file 2' (just using uigetfile). Now I am working out how to do some simple addition/ subtraction of two files and then plot the result (the x data is the same in all files, so I'm just doing arithmetic on the y data). Later on I'll add some buttons/drop down lists for division and multiplication by certain integer factors (e.g. multiply file 1 y data by 2).

What I want to be able to do is to save the result of this plot and do further arithmetic operations on the result, and I will plot the result after each operation on the same axes. When the user closes down the GUI, they will not need to save the session or each operation result, they can just save an image the GUI figure. A new session should begin when the user opens up the GUI again.

Do I need to find some way of temporarily storing the information until the GUI is closed (in order to perform a further operation after each result)? Is there a way to make a temporary variable for each result e.g. result 1, result 2 etc.. so that the user can choose which result to do an operation on?

I want to make this calculator as generic and flexible as possible for the user so that they can go about doing any arithmetic they want on the files. I may even add more import file buttons, in which case the user will need to be able to choose which files to use... e.g. if they wanted to add the data for 3 files or add the data for just 2 files. This would make it a bit more complex, any suggestions on how I could go about organizing the GUI and coding?

I would be very grateful for your help, as I am at a bit of a standstill in my project... Even if you can point me in the right direction, and what things to look up, it would be helpful :) If you need me to clarify anything/ provide more information, please let me know...

Thanks for looking at this question! :)

Vera

EDIT: I think I should be using a buffer for this, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case the only thing you want to do is to store the data as long as the gui runs, there is an argument called handles, that is passed around. Most GUIDE callbacks have a syntax like

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)`
```

The struct `handles` can be used for this purpose. just add a field to this struct inside the callback funcion.

```
handles.res1 = res1;
```

For more information I refer to official matlab documentation [write callbacks using the guide workflow](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-guide-workflow.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's solved my problem of storing data! I will have a look into handles :)